# what's the proper way to handle this invalid api request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an Web API 2 app which accepts a request that looks like this:

```
{
    Type:"RunEtl",
    Entities:["group","user"],
    Domains:["corp-domain-1", "corp-domain-2"],
    UpdatedWithinMinutes:5
}
```

I have code-based validation which validates each property of the request. However, I submitted a request like the following from Postman which returned a server error:

```
{
    Type:"RunEtl",
    Entities:["group","user"],
    Domains
    UpdatedWithinMinutes:5
}
```

How can I update my application to return a response to the user indicating a bad request instead of server error? I was assuming that if the request object was simply malformed as in my first example that the Web API 2 app would automatically return a bad request error to the user.

Comment: "bad request" should never be an user error: your application should validate the user input before sumbitting the request. How the user should handle a "bad request"? User just understands "I have to fill these fields with meaningful (and possibly, mandatory) values". If he does not, warn him before sending the request

Comment: The submitted JSON is not well formed

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if each of the json nodes are filled out, if not then return the node that is empty. In this instance you would return back Domains, since domains is empty

Comment: That isn't a missing or empty JSON node, it's no longer valid JSON (missing comma between properties)

Comment: it seems like .net shouldn't return a 500 when a garbage request is submitted.  there should be some framework-level handling which evaluates requests and returns a 400 if the request is garbage. or is 500 the expected default behavior in web api and for api's in general?